# October CMS | Is there a way to use a Rich Text Editor using the File Upload Widget in Builder?

Tags: widget, octobercms

All I would like to do is when clicking on an image where then I can put in the title and description is then to enter the description with a Rich Text editor rather than the plain text editor which comes built in with the File Upload Widget.

[See image here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TrkJ.png)

Comment: I waited a bit on this to see if anyone would chime in on this cause I was curious to know too. For all intensive purposes though I understand an `img` tag requires an `alt` attribute to be ADA compliant. So typically you would do `<img src="{{img.path}}" alt="{{img.description"}} title="{{img.title}}">`  None of these attributes parse html code or need to be rich text compatible, [check this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_alt.asp). So I would just create a new database column called `imagedescription` which uses a rich text model field.

Comment: Thanks for this. For example, if I'm creating a Carousel, I would want to be able to add a rich text description to each individual image, not exactly for the whole of a gallery. Does that make sense?

Comment: What I would do then is create a database `table_imagedescriptions` and a model. The columns can be id, title, and description. What you then can do `{% if img.title == description.title %} {{ description.description }} {% endif %}` I am sure there are numerous ways to do what you want but this is an example.

Comment: [Check out this video](https://watch-learn.com/making-websites-with-october-cms/making-websites-with-october-cms-part-13-creating-custom-form-widgets) and the next two videos on how to create a form widget. With this you should be able to create the descriptions in the model controller where you create your galleries.

Comment: Hi there, I still didn't manage to figure this out! I've been doing other things in the meantime but your tips for the previous plugin came in really handy.